# How can I compile Vim with +clientserver?

Tags: vim

I don't see a `./configure` option for `+clientserver` specifically.  How do I enable it?

I'm on OS X (Lion).  From some googling, it sounds like `+clientserver` requires an X server, but my MacVim installation has it, despite no X server, and the author of [this post](http://www.scarpa.name/2011/03/22/vim-and-the-terminal/) uses it purely in the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`+clientserver`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html) requires some form of IPC to discover the server and send commands to it.

On Unix, Vim uses X11 (the GUI feature) for this – the author of that post *does* mention that they are using Vim inside `urxvt`, an X11 terminal.

[On OS X,](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/master/runtime/doc/remote.txt#L205) the MacVim fork additionally has support for ["distributed objects"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Distributed_Objects), an OS X-specific concept. Again, this requires GUI support to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks a *bunch* for this clear and short introduction. Thank to MacVim and lots of tutorials on the internet, I was under impression that vim on Linux supports that too.

Comment: @lzap: It does, yes – when compiled with X11 support.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason Fedora and Red Hat derivates does not have it. And it makes sense - I don't want X11 to be installed on text-only server...

Comment: So it's not possible to compile with `clientserver` unless using MacVim?